# Is there any events that are `specific layout handle based` or `specific controller based`?

Tags: layout, event-observer

So I have a situation where I really need to observe an event which is `layout handle` specific. In my case, I want to set a root template for the handle `catalog_category_default`. I think I can use `controller_action_layout_load_before` for this purpose. But as its name indicates it may call every time a controller tries to load a layout(I am not sure about this point). Since there are lot of controllers out there (We all know Magento is a giant system !!), I feel this event is inappropriate in my case. It is enough if I can listen to a catalog controller based layout loading event, so that unwanted `observations` can be avoided ? So my question is

1. Can we have `particular layout handle based` or a `particular controller based`  events ?
2. If I listen to `controller_action_layout_load_before`, is that making unwanted observations ? Is it affect magento performance ?

Comment: why dont you modify the template from its block class? that would be specific.

Comment: i dont like rewrite methods. it is always recommended that, we need use observers if it is possible.

Comment: as you want to modify a specific handle, then rewrite would be better than getting the observer method called each time

Comment: Yes. You are correct. But question is a doubt. I need clarification more on this

Comment: i did check list of events, http://huztechbuzz.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/complete-list-of-all-events-in-magento/ , i could not locate a specific one

Comment: Is it possible to create custom events?

Comment: yes but if you would hook in your custom event, then you need to rewrite a core file to fire that event

Comment: I checked out your link. Its a nice article. Thanks for sharing your time. You are right. It would be nice if we go with rewrite in this particular case

Comment: yea it would have been interesting if there would have been a solution to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There are some pages that have specific events, but it's not a general case.
   For example, for the category page you have events, `catalog_controller_category_init_before` and `catalog_controller_category_init_after` but those are dispatched before the layout is loaded. So you don't have access to the page blocks in those events.
   For the product page you have the events `catalog_controller_product_init_before` and `catalog_controller_product_init` but again you don't have access to the layout.
2. Sure `controller_action_layout_load_before` will make unwanted observations. It is dispatched for all pages, but I don't think the impact is very big. If you write your observers correctly this shouldn't be visible. I mean, the first thing you should do is to check if your observer is dispached from the right page. If not, just return nothing.

For the rest of you problem, changing layouts in different cases I already wrote an answer here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/29329/146

Comment: I learned a lot from you. Thanks for your each and every outstanding answers

Answer (score 1):

```
public function someFunc($observer)
    {
      $action = $observer->getEvent()->getAction();
      $actionName = $action->getFullActionName();
      if($actionName == 'catalog_category_default')
      {
        // your code.
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please read question.