# How to update `catalog_category_view` using observer?

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer, update-handle

I am trying to set a `root template` to handler `catalog_category_view` through an observer. I know I can achieve it through layout update. But believe me I really need to dynamically set root template for handler. :)

The event that I am observing is `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` and my observer is shown below

### Observer.php

```
<?php

class Programmerrkt_Productperrow_Model_Observer

    public function setPrdouctListPage($observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();

        $layout_template = 'page/2columns-left';

        $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('catalog_category_view')->addUpdate('<reference name="root"><action method="setTemplate"><template>'.$layout_template.'</template></action></reference>');

        return;
     }
}
```

Please note that, my event is observing my magento. Means config settings are correct.

But the code didn't work. It is not updating `catalog_category_view` handler. What is the possible cause for this.?

### EDIT

When I output all layout, layout handler look like this

```
[catalog_category_view] => Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element Object
(
    [reference] => Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element Object
    (
       [@attributes] => Array
       (
           [name] => product_list
       )

       [action] => Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element Object
       (
           [@attributes] => Array
           (
               [method] => addPriceBlockType
           )

           [type] => bundle
           [block] => bundle/catalog_product_price
           [template] => bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml
       )

    )

)
```

As you can see its not updating.

Share your thoughts please.

Comment: Try to use controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before observer event and i think you need to put $layout->generateXml(); to generate xml

Comment: `But believe me I really need to dynamically set root template for handler. :)` well now I am interested. Why do you need to set it dynamically :)

Comment: @DavidManners : Thanks for your reply. I am planning to create a module, that will allow us to set product list page's layout and no. of products that need to show in the  page. For that I am using this

Comment: @DavidManners: page layout and no of products in a row is setting thorough system->config. This part is complete. Now according to this values I need to set root template and update `addColumnCountLayoutDepend()` method of product list block. So for that I am using this observer

Comment: @DavidManners : Please ask  if you did't get me. I will edit my question and then  detaily explain what I wana achieve :)

Comment: @Mufaddal : I tried your solution and it seems to be not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try observing the event `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after`.
This is triggered after the blocks are generated. Just change the root template.

```
public function setPrdouctListPage($observer) {
    $action = $observer->getEvent()->getAction(); 
    $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
    if ($action->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view') {
        $root = $layout->getBlock('root');
        if ($root) {
            $root->setTemplate('page/2columns-left.phtml');
        }
    }
}
```

The down side of this is that the event is dispathced for every page. Even if your method does nothign for the rest of the pages it may impact (very little) the performance.

I think there is an other event you can use.
When viewing a category, the event `catalog_controller_category_init_after` is dispatched. that receives as parameter the current category.
You can use that and the category custom design settings to achieve what you need.

```
public function setPrdouctListPage($observer) {
    $category = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory(); 
    $category->setPageLayout('two_columns_left');
    //or if you want to set different page layouts depending on what is loaded `catalog_category_layered` or `catalog_category_default` you can do this. 

   if ($category->getIsAnchor()) {
       $category->setPageLayout('LAYOUT FOR anchor page here'); //this means `catalog_category_layered` is loaded
   }
   else {
        $category->setPageLayout('LAYOUT FOR non anchor page here'); //this means `catalog_category_default` is loaded
   }
}
```

This should act just like setting the `2columns-left` layout from the backend.

As you can see I'm not questioning why you don't set this layout from the backend. I trust you have a reason. I just stated it here for future readers.

Comment: thanks for providing info about `specific event`. I have asked a question before http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/27472/is-there-any-events-that-are-specific-layout-handle-based-or-specific-control, in which I actually try to get this anwer. I got it as accident. Thanks

Comment: Ha. Maybe I should copy paste this answer to your other question :)

Comment: With all respect, I want to say that, I need to set my root template to `catalog_category_view` handler. Because later I am going to set root template for `catalog_category_default`,`catalog_category_layered`, `CATEGORY_{ID}` ETC.

Comment: If that is the case I will accept that answer. But as you note, I have asked that qn so generally. But this sitution is specific

Comment: please read the comments that I provided just below my qn. Situation well explained there. Looking forward for your valuable comments

Comment: `catalog_category_default` and `catalog_category_layered` don't have pages associated to them. They are loaded along with the `catalog_category_view` handle on the category view page, depending is the category is marked as anchor or not.  I think you can use the same event `catalog_controller_category_init_after ` (my second suggestion) to handle both cases. `_view` and `_layered`/`_default`. I will modify the code in the answer to give you an idea.

Comment: Oh god !! I was thinking about this thing also. I have gone through `catalog.xml` and observed that there is no `root` set for those handles!!! But I couldn't find `catalog_category_view` definition either!!! I can set `root` for `CATEGORY_ID` handler right ?

Comment: Yeah `catalog_category_view` is not defined, but it is still loaded. If you add blocks to it it will work. As for the `root`, this is not set in most of the handles. It uses the general one from `page.xml`. And I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "I can set root for CATEGORY_ID handler right ?". `CATEGORY_ID` it is loaded along with the other layout handles in the category page (if it exists).

Comment: Means if I set `root template` for `CATEGORY_ID` handler, whether it cover `catalog_category_view`'s root template and render that specific template that I set in `CATEGORY_ID` for that specific category?

Comment: There is one more doubt. Can I update the `addColumnCountLayoutDepend()` for `product_list` block using  `catalog_controller_category_init_after` event ? or whether I need to listen any other event ?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't. Like I said, in that event you don't have access to the blocks and the method `addColumnCountLayoutDepend` is applied for blocks