# Grid view column count for mobile devices

Tags: category

For desktop websites I've configured Magento to have 3 columns on category pages due to which when I see it on mobile devices, it shows 2 products in a row and 1 product in next row and it repeats the same again.

In list.phtml `<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>` I can update `$_columnCount` with 2 but again it will affect desktop devies.

I want to set 2 columns for mobile devices and 3 columns for desktop. How I can achieve it?

Comment: How have you define a request mobille and destop?

Comment: Do you have responsive design or you have any different theme or store for mobile device ?

Comment: @AkhileshPatel: I'm working on rwd theme and writing custom css to make it responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add mobile check by using this `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

```
if (preg_match("/Mobile|Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|Windows Phone/", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
      //use your condition here for column count

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to fulfill ***your requirement you need do track agent is Mobile  browser***.

And using **Observer create a new layout handler**.On this handler,you need to set `root layout` template `3-columns.phtml` .

- Use Zend libary function
  **`Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile::match($userAgent=Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent(),
  $server=$_SERVER);`**  **for  track** the current user agent **coming
  from Mobile**
- use **`controller_action_layout_load_before`** for fire an observer
  which will create **new handler** whenever `current user agent is
  coming from Mobile`.
- On  that new handler you will set *3-columns.phtml* as **root
  template** for coming Mobile

**Handler Format:**  `Mobile_PAGE`

**Observer code:**

```
<?php
class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observe{ 
/**
     * Before load layout event handler
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function beforeLoadLayout($observer)
    {
        if($observer->getEvent()->getAction()->getFullActionName()=='catalog_category_view'){
        $IsCurrentDriveMob=Zend_Http_UserAgent_Mobile::match($userAgent=Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpUserAgent(), $server=$_SERVER);
        if($IsCurrentDriveMob):
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
                    $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('Mobile_PAGE');
        // check all Handler 
        //Zend_Debug::dump($layout->getUpdate()->getHandles());
        endif;
        }
    return ;
    }


}
```

**Config.xml code;**

```
<global>
    <models>
        <[MyCustomModule_Model_Class_Groupname]>
            <class>[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model</class>
        </[MyCustomModule_Model_Class_Groupname]>
    </models>
</global>
   <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <my_current_page_is_observer>
                        <class>[MyCustomModule_Model_Class_Groupname]/observer</class>
                        <method>beforeLoadLayout</method>
                    </my_current_page_is_observer>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
     </events>
   </frontend>
```

**Now on this of this handler,you can add a new block to layout  and a new phtml.**

**Now you can change template using Mobile_PAGE hanlder**

```
<Mobile_PAGE>
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
</reference
</Mobile_PAGE>
```

---

Also ,you can use *controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after* event.Check this event use at [Marius answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/29329/4564)